# Shell script reading windows registry

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need some help for a small shell script which is supposed to read the nvidia driver version from the windows registry.

Basically, the windows command (which works fine in dos prompt) is the following:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer" /v Version
```

So naturally, I try to run it from the shell script:

```
CMD //C 'REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer" /v Version'
```

But it says that the key name is invalid. My guess is that the double quotes are misinterpreted (because of wrong syntax most likely).

I have tried several things like entering this code in a batch script and executing the batch from shell. The same problem occurs.

Can anybody help on this ?

Thanks in advance!

Pat

Answer (score 3):

//C is not valid cmd.exe syntax, use /C.

But there is no need to use cmd /C in a batch file, use call: `call someapp.exe`

' is not legal as a quote.

Try:

```
call REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer" /v Version
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed to mention I was executing this script from mingw32. The //C is valid and the problem I had was because of the 32/64 bit difference and the place in the registry. I solved it by calling the native command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

i use this in Java:

start = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "reg",  "export", "path",

as mentioned before:
call REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer" /v Version

should work as well