# Reading a registry value to a batch variable, handling spaces in value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm struggling to read the value of a registry key into a variable. The registry value may, or may not, contain spaces. In this case I'm trying to look up SDK paths.

It's easy to get the value with `reg query`, but it's returned in a remarkably unhelpful format:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools
    InstallationFolder    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\
```

The key name, key type, and key value are separated by a series of spaces, not tabs.

You'd think you could use something like:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3* skip=2" %%L IN (
    `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder`
) DO SET sdkpath=%%L
```

... but if the key contains spaces, as in this case, the result emitted on the command line is:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>SET sdkpath=C:\Program
```

Which isn't helpful. There doesn't seem to be a wildcard variable to say "All matches". And you can't just write:

```
DO SET sdkpath=%%L %%M
```

... because if there are *not* spaces in the path, that will produce a literal `%M` (and would also produce a trailing space).

So. Is there any way to do this simple thing in a batch file?

I've written most of my tooling in Powershell (and some Perl), but I need to use a batch file for the "simple" task of `call`ing the visual studio / windows sdk environment script and then invoking the code in sane languages once the environment is set up.

You'd think that after 10+ years of `cmd.exe`'s existence, and `command.com` before it, this would be easy. Help?

(I can use Perl and the `Win32::` packages to query the registry, but it doesn't help me get it into a batch var...)

Using Win2k12.

I've read:

- [Read registry value that contains spaces using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16281185/398670)
- [Shell script reading windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871294/398670)

and many others, but none handle the *general case* of correctly reading a value from a key without knowing whether or not it contains spaces / how many.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah this is one of the annoying details about the `for /f` command.  In order to read all the characters including the spaces with the `*` the **previous** token needs to be declared. `tokens=2,*`  The functional reason is stated in the documentation.

> If the last character in the tokens= string is an asterisk (*), an **additional variable** is allocated and receives the remaining text on the line after the last token that is parsed.

[FOR Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%L IN (
    `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\WinSDKTools" /v InstallationFolder`
) DO SET sdkpath=%%M
```

Comment: Wow. Now I hate batch files more than ever. But thankyou SO much.

Comment: If you're like me and have reading comprehension issues, note that %%L automatically becomes %%M.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quotation marks

`SET "sdkpath=%%M"`

instead `SET sdkpath=%%M`

This will avoid problems with spaces.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, it should be a comment to David Ruhmann's answer

Comment: Yes u are right, but i can't comment his post. (<50 reputation).