Task Scheduler Script on startup not setting enviroment variables
I wish to run pico-env.cmd on Windows Start-up to set up development environment for my Raspberry Pi Pico.
I've configured this in Task Scheduler to run at startup as administrator.
The task is running but environment variables are not being set.
Note: The script was provided by SDK installer. I'm the only user in Windows.
Script
@if not defined _echo echo off

set errors=0
goto main

:AddToPath

  if exist "%~1" (
    set "PATH=%~1;%PATH%"
  )

  goto :EOF

:VerifyExe

  echo Checking %1...
  cmd /c %2 >NUL 2>NUL
  if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo ERROR: %1 is required but was not found.
    set /a errors += 1
  )

  goto :EOF

:SetEnvFromRegistry

  rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352793/reading-a-registry-value-to-a-batch-variable-handling-spaces-in-value
  for /f "usebackq tokens=2,*" %%h in (
    `"reg query "HKCU\%PICO_REG_KEY%" /v "%1Path" 2>NUL | find /i "%1Path""`
    ) do (
    echo PICO_%1_PATH=%%i
    set "PICO_%1_PATH=%%i"
  )

  goto :EOF

:main

pushd "%~dp0"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (version.ini) do (
  echo %%i
  set "%%i"
)

popd

if not defined PICO_SDK_VERSION (
  echo ERROR: Unable to determine Pico SDK version.
  set /a errors += 1
)

if "%~1" neq "" (
  reg add "HKCU\%PICO_REG_KEY%" /v ReposPath /d "%~1" /f
)

set "PICO_SDK_PATH=%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\pico-sdk"

call :SetEnvFromRegistry repos

for %%i in (examples extras playground) do (
  rem Environment variables in Windows aren't case-sensitive, so we don't need
  rem to bother with uppercasing the env var name.
  if exist "%PICO_REPOS_PATH%\pico-%%i" (
    echo PICO_%%i_PATH=%PICO_REPOS_PATH%\pico-%%i
    set "PICO_%%i_PATH=%PICO_REPOS_PATH%\pico-%%i"
  )
)

if exist "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\openocd" (
  echo OPENOCD_SCRIPTS=%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\openocd\scripts
  set "OPENOCD_SCRIPTS=%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\openocd\scripts"
  set "PATH=%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\openocd;%PATH%"
)

rem Set the CMake generator explicitly
set CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja

rem GDB warns about being unable to determine a path for the index cache
rem directory if we do not set this.
set "HOME=%USERPROFILE%"

call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\cmake\bin"
call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\gcc-arm-none-eabi\bin"
call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\ninja"
call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\python"
call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\git\cmd"
call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\pico-sdk-tools"
call :AddToPath "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\picotool"

call :VerifyExe "GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain" "arm-none-eabi-gcc --version"
call :VerifyExe "CMake" "cmake --version"
call :VerifyExe "Ninja" "ninja --version"
call :VerifyExe "Python 3" "python --version"
call :VerifyExe "Git" "git --version"

rem We need Visual Studio Build Tools to compile pioasm and elf2uf2, but only
rem if we do not have pre-compiled versions available.
if not exist "%PICO_INSTALL_PATH%\pico-sdk-tools" (
  call :AddToPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"
  call :AddToPath "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"

  rem https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Start-Developer-Command-Prompt

  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`vswhere.exe -products * -requires "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64" -latest -property installationPath`) do (
    if exist "%%i\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" (
      call "%%i\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat"
    )
  )

  call :VerifyExe "Visual Studio" "cl"
)

exit /b %errors%

